# Android: Update some weather Data from server every X hours

Tags: java, android, scheduling, alarmmanager

What is the best and most efficient way in android to schedule an update for some weather data from the server every X hours?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about scheduling system, a good way is using `AlarmManager`, which can wake up your activity even if it is not running.

Here is some info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

And here a nice example with `Notification`: http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/alarm-notification

Answer (score 3):

Register your app with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).